# Can I get password toggle without TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, android-widget

I just wanted that eye button to let user toggle password (so that they can verify what they have typed). I found a solution here in StackOverflow; it was using `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`. The problem is that it is noticeably thicker than normal `EditText`.

My EditText is not inside a text input layout, because I do not want that hint animation, etc. I do not want to hard-code their height, because it may vary depending on the system language and themes.

Can I get the toggle feature with normal EditText? OR can I make TextInputEditText have the same height as EditText?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:background="#66FF0000"
        android:text="This is normal EditText"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#660000FF"
            android:hint="This is TextInputEditText"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems that the TextInputLayout that makes this issue. I have asked another question for it. [Preventing TextInputLayout from making TextInputEditText taller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707950/preventing-textinputlayout-from-making-textinputedittext-taller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Code

```
 public void ShowPasswordCheckBoxListener(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            if (!checked)
                password1.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());  //hide the password from the edit text
            else
               password1.setTransformationMethod(new DoNothingTransformation()); //show the password from the edit text
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if (!checked)
                password2.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod()); //hide the password from the edit text
            else
                password2.setTransformationMethod(null); // another option show the password from the edit text
            break;
    }
}     //password1 and password2 are your normal edittext
```

Comment: By this way, we do not get that eye but we must add an external UI (button or checkbox) to let users toggle it, right?

Comment: YES you need to another UI for showing or hiding the password in edit text but in this case i use the checkbox. Without any external UI user can not use the password hiding and showing feature dynamically.If you want to use by default password in edittext then simply use the  `android:password` in editext

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library

```
compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
```

check [this](http://www.digitstory.com/android-password-visibility-edittext/#.WsYk7ohua9I) link for more information.