# Preventing TextInputLayout from making TextInputEditText taller

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I want that password toggle feature, and it seems `TextInputLayout` has that feature, not `TextInputEditText`. But as you see the code below, even though I set the height to `wrap_content` and `app:hintEnabled="false"`, the height of `TextInputEditText`gets taller if the `TextInputEditText` is in `TextInputLayout`.  Compare that to the height of the `TextInputEditText` outside the `TextInputLayout`.

Since I do not use that hint animation, there is no need that the `TextInputLayout` to increase the height of `TextInputEditText`. How can I prevent `TextInputLayout` from increasing the height of `TextInputEditText`?

[image: Screenshot of an emulator screen.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:background="#66FF0000"
        android:text="Normal EditText"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#660000FF"
            android:hint="TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#6600FF00"
        android:hint="TextInputEditText"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution I have found so far is to set  `android:layout_height` to fixed size. For example 40dp.